# Getting error while executing a shell script to check for a particular character in each line at a specific position and if found replace it with "X"

Tags: shell

I have this shell script. And in this script i am trying to find a character at a specific position  in every line and if at that position the caharacter is found then replace it with "X"

```
filename = "/ray/test/raymond/test2.data"

if [ -r $filename ]; then
    echo " File Found..."
    echo " "
fi
cat $filename | 
while read line
  do

      var = `echo $line | awk '{print substr($0, 422, 1)}'`
      if [ "$var" = "D" ]; then

        `echo $line | awk '{start = substr ($0, 1, 421); end = substr ($0, 423); print start "X" end}'` >> new_file

      else
        `echo $line` >> new_file
      fi
  done
```

But i am getting following error while executing the script:

/ray/test/raymond$ ksh ray2.sh
ray2.sh[3]: filename:  not found
File Found...

ray2.sh[14]: b:  not found

ray2.sh[14]: b:  not found

ray2.sh[14]: b:  not found

and i am not sure why. And this i am doing in solaris 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'll show 2 examples hopefully they can give an idea.
Example 1

```
filename = "/ray/test/raymond/test2.data"
if [ -f "$filename" -a -r "$filename" ]; then
       while read -r line; do
              if [ "${line:421:1}" = 'D' ]; then
                     printf '%s%s%s\n' "${line:0:420}" 'X' "${line:422}" >> "$new_file"
              else
                     printf '%s\n' "$line" >> "$new_file"
              fi
       done < "$filename"
elif [ ! -f "$filename" ]; then
      echo 'ERROR: Not a file'
      return 1
elif [ ! -r "$filename" ]; then
     echo 'ERROR: Can not read the file'
     return 1
fi
```

Example 2

```
filename = "/ray/test/raymond/test2.data"
new_file="$filename"'_new.txt'
if [ -f "$filename" -a -r "$filename" ]; then
       output="$new_file" awk 'BEGIN { output=ENVIRON["output"] }
       {
               if(substr($0, 422, 1) == "D") {
                       $0=sprintf("%s%s%s", substr($0, 1, 421), "X", substr($0, 423))
               }
               print $0 >> output
       }' "$filename"
elif [ ! -f "$filename" ]; then
      echo 'ERROR: Not a file'
      return 1
elif [ ! -r "$filename" ]; then
     echo 'ERROR: Can not read the file'
     return 1
fi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But i realized that replacing the 422 byte of every line with a 'X' in a file will not server my purpose, i need to encrypt it so that i cn decrypt it when i need. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Encryption? Of course you can. You can use ``openssl`` for that. There are many types of encodings you can pick too. ``AES-128-CBC`` is probably good enough for your purpose I think. This encoding is usually use in HLS (HTTP Live Streaming).

Comment: For example to encrypt your file: ``openssl aes-128-cbc -K 0x1234567812345678 -iv 0x0000000000000000 -in "$filename" -out "$new_file"``. To decrypt it: ``openssl aes-128-cbc -d -K 0x1234567812345678 -iv 0x0000000000000000 -in "$new_file" -out "$decrypted_file"``. Just like any other encodings, you have to remember the key (and IV in this case) you're using. The key in this example is 0x1234567812345678 and the IV is 0x0000000000000000.